# Approximations of modules in a special setting

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a local finite dimensional nonselfinjective algebra $A$ and $M:=A \oplus D(A)$. Can one find a general formula for the minimal right add(M)-approximation of a general indecomposable module $N$ and the corresponding kernel? If it helps one might assume that A is local or some other things first.